# Confusion related to adding noise to a gaussian data

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process, white-noise

I have this confusion related to two methods to add gaussian white noise to data.

Suppose I have a bivariate gaussian distribution with mean vector and covariance matrix
$$
\mu = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0.5 \\0.5 &  1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now suppose I want to add a gaussian white noise. I want to know what is the difference between the following methods.

**Method A**
Generate samples from the bivariate Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$, and then adding noise with zero mean and unit variance like

for each i

data(i,1) = data(i,1) + $\epsilon_1$

data(i,2) = data(i,2) + $\epsilon_2$

where $\epsilon_1$ & $\epsilon_2$  is noise ~ N(0,1)

**Method B**
Generate samples from a Gaussian distribution distribution with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma + \sigma^2I$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix

and $\sigma^2$ is the noise variance set to 1
Are these methods equivalent?

Comment: Your question will be clearer and accessible to many more people if you edit it to use standard mathematical and statistical notation rather than some unexplained computer language. Moreover, once you make that effort, the answer ought to be glaringly obvious, because the mathematical formulation makes the parameters of the two distributions apparent and invites a simple quantitative comparison.

Comment: @whuber. I have changed the notation. I have experimented with the two methods and I have got the same results. So they should be same.

Comment: In method A, it's not clear to me what you want to do. Do you add a different value $\epsilon_{ij}$ to each elements of data, or is it one value $\epsilon_1$ for all first components and one value $\epsilon_2$ for all second components, or is it the same value $\epsilon$ for all values in the sample?

Comment: @QuantIbex. I means add noise with mean 0 and variance 1. gaussian noise(standard). In method 2 add independent gaussian noise with variance equal to 1. that's why we had the identity matrix there

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't answer my question. The notation used in your question suggests that it is the **same value**, say 0.12, which is added to **all elements** of the matrix `data`. Is it really what you meant?

Comment: @QuantIbex. I have added more info

Comment: You haven't clearly responded to the direct question @Quantibex asked. You used $\epsilon_i$ twice. Is it meant to be the same value both times? It *matters*, since the answer to your question changes depending on what the answer is. If you are not clearly explicit when asked, you cannot hope to get good answers. As you have written it, it's the same value both times and the answer to your question is "No, they're different" ... though the margins are the same. Look at the correlations between them.

Comment: @Glen_b. I have changed the notation. I hope it makes sense now. Could you please explain why they are different? I couldn't get the intuition behind it

Comment: The two things in your question are no longer different, since your recent edit -- the new ($\epsilon_1$, $\epsilon_2$) are quite different from the previous ($\epsilon_i$, $\epsilon_i$), since the first thing is two different, independent objects while the second thing (which you had before) is the same object twice ... identical variables are perfectly correlated.